# Calling detach() at the end of the thread

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I have a working thread similar to the following code. In `begin_work`, it will check whether the working thread is executing before creating a new working thread. However, `begin_work` will never create the next working thread when the current thread is exited until I call `end_work`.

I have tried to call `detach` at the end of the thread and it works fine. Is it safe to call `detach` at the end of the thread? Or, how can I do to safely create the next working thread without calling `end_work` before calling `begin_work`?

```
class thread_worker {
private:
    std::thread worker;
    // ... other menbers

public:
    thread_worker() {};
    ~thread_worker() { end_work(); };

    void begin_work() {
        if (!worker.joinable()) {
            worker = std::thread { &thread_worker::do_work, this };
        }
    }

    void do_work() {
        // ... access other members ...

        if (exit not by notify) {
            worker.detach();    // can I call detach?
        }
    }

    void end_work() {
        if (worker.joinable()) {
            // notify worker to exit
            worker.join();
        } 
    }
};
```

**Edit:**

My purpose is to call `begin_work` without block. If there is one working thread on execution, then the function will return directly or returns an `is_working` error. Otherwise, create a new working thread seamlessly.

Since `std::thread::joinable()` always returns `true` until `join` or `detach` is called. As a result, the future call of `begin_work` will never create the new working thread even though the current working thread has exited.

Therefore, I need a mechanism to automatically detach at the end of the thread.

Comment: `std::thread` isn't thread safe, why not just call `end_work()` at the beginning of `begin_work`?

Comment: Since `begin_work` neet to keep the current working thread when it is running. `end_work` is called only when the user exits the application.

Comment: @Kai `std::thread::join` does not end the current working thread. It will "keep" it and wait until it ends.

Comment: @Kai hmm..didn't you say `begin_work` only creates new thread when the previous thread's exited? So how can further threads be created? If your intention is to call `end_work` at the end of application exit, you probably want multiple threads running at the same time.

Comment: This seems to be kind-of an XY problem to me. I would recommend to describe what you are really trying to solve by defining `thread_worker` class. What is its purpose? How is it supposed to be used?

Comment: To add to what @DanielLangr said, detaching a thread doesn't make it exit. Yes, you can call detach(), but the thread will continue to run.

Comment: @Daniel Since in `end_work`, it will notify the current thread to exit before calling `join()`, the current working thread will be cut immediately when receiving the exit notification. If I call `begin_work` several times, only the last working thread can be done.

Comment: @Kai I have updated my answer based on your edit.

Comment: @PP Thanks for your answer. I think `w_done` needs to be initialized to `true`. Otherwise, the working thread will never begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried to call detach at the end of the thread and it works fine

There's *data race* in the access to `worker` - it's undefined behaviour. When `begin_work` tests `worker.joinable()`, `do_work` might be detaching it at the same time (the call to `worker.detach()`).

You can instead detach the immediately when creating it:

```
worker = std::thread { &thread_worker::do_work, this };
worker.detach();
```

However, this can leave multiple threads running at the same time, which contradicts your requirement of running one worker thread at a time (but why only one? that just makes threading pointless).

Instead you can do:

```
void begin_work() {
    end_work();
    worker = std::thread { &thread_worker::do_work, this };
}
```

which ensures the previous thread completed.

---

Based on yuor edit, you only need to check whether you can *join* without wait - that seems to be reason you want to detach. You can instead do that with an atomic flag. Basically, you just to take care of the *data race* noted above.

```
class thread_worker {
private:
    std::thread worker;
    std::atomic_bool w_done {true};
    
    // ... other menbers

public:
    thread_worker() {};
    ~thread_worker() { end_work(); };

    void begin_work() {
        if (w_done) {
            end_work();   
            worker = std::thread { &thread_worker::do_work, this };
        }
    }

    void do_work() {
        // ... access other members ...

        w_done = true;
    }

    void end_work() {
        w_done = false;
        if (worker.joinable()) {
            // notify worker to exit
            worker.join();
        } 
    }
};
```